# Using scatterplot to display image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot image data using scatterplot. This may sound silly, but I'm hoping to extend this to 3 dimensions in order to try to view a 3-dimensional.

When I do

```
pylab.imshow(my_img, cmap=pylab.cm.gist_yarg)
```

I have no problems seeing my image. But when I try

```
ax.scatter(np.arange(my_img.shape[0]), 
           np.arange(my_img.shape[1]), 
           c=my_img, cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg)
```

I get mostly black pixels. Why is this? Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The [`scatter()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) function plots one point for each pair of values in the arrays you pass for `x` and `y` arguments. In your example, the value of these arrays would be `[0, 1, 2, ..., my_img.shape[0]-1]` and `[0, 1, 2, ..., my_img.shape[1]-1]`. At best, this will plot a diagonal line and, if `x` and `y` aren't the same size (i.e., your image isn't square), `scatter()` should throw an error that `x and y must be the same size`.

In order to plot all of the pixels in the image, you have to pass `scatter()` the coordinates for every pixel. One way to get the coordinates for every element in an array is [`indicies()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html#numpy.indices) command from `numpy`. You only want the indices of the outermost values, not the RGB values stored for each pixel, so only pass it the first two values of the shape.

```
y, x = np.indices( my_img.shape[:2] )
```

Now `x` and `y` are 2-D arrays that represent the coordinates for every point in the 2-D image.

The other thing you have to do is to reshape the image array so that it is of dimension Nx3, where N is the length of the total number of pixels in the image. This is done with the [`.reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method of the array.

```
colors = my_img.reshape((-1,3))
```

The `-1` passed to reshape tells `reshape()` to calculate that dimension automatically, so you don't have to pass it the number of pixels explicitly.

Now the `scatter()` command is:

```
ax.scatter( x, y, c=colors )
ax.invert_yaxis() #make y=0 appear at the top, similar to imshow()
```

Finally, you want to apply a color map. If you pass RGB values for color, `scatter()` and `imshow()` ignore the `cmap` parameter. You'll have to convert the RGB values into a single value as shown in the [matplotlib Image tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html).

NOTE: Drawing the plots this way is slow and may not be suitable for large images!

Comment: Very good answer. But it implicitely assumes that the image has several color channels and that the colors in the scatter would correspond to the colors in the image. Seeing that the question uses a colormap, I think one can assume that the image here is a simple 2D array, making the solution much easier, `y, x = np.indices(my_img.shape); ax.scatter( x, y, c=my_img)`.